# Find and replace in TinyMCE 4

Tags: replace, tinymce, find

Looking for a way to find and replace content pasted or entered in TinyMCE 4 editor. I'm a TinyMCE newbie and I can't find a solution anywhere.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tinymce parameters [paste_preprocess](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3apaste_preprocess) and [paste_postprocess](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3apaste_postprocess). THey allow you to modify what has been pasted into the editor.